# How to hide components when keyboard is up?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to hide components when the keyboard shows, aside from installing packages?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'hide' but you should check out KeyboardAvoidingView https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview#__docusaurus it basically makes the whole Keyboard display more elegant, especially on Android.

Answer (score 2):

For those using functional components, here is a hook that you could use to detect when the keyboard is opened and closed.

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { Keyboard } from "react-native";

const useKeyboardOpen = () => {
  const [isKeyboardOpen, setIsKeyboardOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardOpenListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () =>
      setIsKeyboardOpen(true)
    );
    const keyboardCloseListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () =>
      setIsKeyboardOpen(false)
    );

    return () => {
      if (keyboardOpenListener) keyboardOpenListener.remove();
      if (keyboardCloseListener) keyboardCloseListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return isKeyboardOpen;
};

export default useKeyboardOpen;
```

And this is how I use it in my projects:

```js
import { useTheme } from "react-native-paper";
import useKeyboardOpen from "hooks/useKeyboardOpen";

export const Login = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isKeyboardOpen = useKeyboardOpen();
  const styles = useStyles(theme, isKeyboardOpen);

  return ( 
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <View style = {styles.logo}>
        <Logo />
      </View> 
      <View style = {styles.form}>   
          ....   
      </View> 
    </View>
  );
};

const useStyles = (theme, isKeyboardOpen) = (
  StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    logo: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 20,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      ...(isKeyboardOpen && {
        display: "none",
      }),
    },
    form: {
      flex: 1,
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code sample from the [Keyboard](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard) documentation, I would do something like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
  state = {keyboardOpen: false};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow,
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this._keyboardDidHide,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    this.setState({
      keyboardOpen: true
    });
  }

  _keyboardDidHide() {
    this.setState({
      keyboardOpen: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {!this.state.keyboardOpen && <MyComponent />}
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, in `componentDidMount` you subscribe to the `show` and `hide` keyboard events. You keep track of the Keyboard current state in your Component `state` thanks to `this.state.keyboardOpen` and you conditionally display `MyComponent` based on the value of `this.state.keyboardOpen` in your `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

I made this into a npm package if anyone is interested.
https://github.com/TIKramer/react-native-hide-onkeyboard

You can hide the view by using HideOnKeyboard> </HideOnKeyboard